# How to save and restore network architektur in tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

I am looking for a way to save and restore a network-structure with tflearn (tflearn.org). The embeded model.save takes care about the weights persistance. But in case I want to forget about the network structure and load it again, I have to build the net again. Therefore I have to "remember" the structure (layers, amount of neurons) and so on.

I've experimented with pickle (something like pickle.dump(net)) and tf.train.import_meta_graph (combine tflearn.org with tensorflow) without success.

Lets say I have a training like this:

```
from future import division, print_function, absolute_import

import numpy as np
import tflearn

import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist

X, Y, testX, testY = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)
X = np.reshape(X, (-1, 28, 28))

testX = np.reshape(testX, (-1, 28, 28))

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 28, 28])
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128, return_seq=True)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128)
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam',
loss='categorical_crossentropy', name="output1")
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=2,tensorboard_dir='lstm')
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=1, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True,
snapshot_step=100)

model.save('lstm_load.tflearn')
```

Later I want to restore all needed stuff in a different program or session like this (pseudo-like code does not work of course ;-))

```
from future import division, print_function, absolute_import

import numpy as np
import tflearn

import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist

X, Y, testX, testY = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)
X = np.reshape(X, (-1, 28, 28))

testX = np.reshape(testX, (-1, 28, 28))

model = model.load_everything("model.tfl")
prediction = model.predict([X])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read the official guide on [saving and restoring models](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model)?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I haven't seen this guide in version 1.3 yet. I'll give it a try if it works together with tflearn.org. Especially this par: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#models

Comment: This guide does not seem to work with tf 1.3.0rc2. AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'saved_model_builder'

Comment: Look into the `tensorflow.python.saved_model` namespace.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. I was able to save a model. Though I still have to restore it.